# Envoy to envoy TLS for TLS proxy

Tags: sni, envoyproxy

Assume this artitecture

```
                             ................................................
                             .                                              .
                             .                                              .
                             .                                              .
                             .                                              .
                   ┌───────────────────┐                            ┌─────────────────┐
┌──────────────────┤ Customer Firewall ├─┐     ┌────────────────────┤Provider Firewall├─┐
│                  └──────────┬────────┘ │     │Provider Network    └──┬──────────────┘ │
│   Customer Network          │          │     │             ┌─────────┴─┐              │
│                             │          │     │       ┌─────┤ Envoy - B ├───────┐      │
│                             │          │     │       │     └─────┬─────┘       │      │
│                      ┌──────┴─────┐    │     │       │           │             │      │
│       ┌─────────┐    │            │    │     │       │           │             │      │
│       │ Client  ├────┤  Envoy - A │    │     │  ┌────┴────┐  ┌───┴─────┐  ┌────┴────┐ │
│       └─────────┘    │            │    │     │  │ Service │  │ Service │  │ Service │ │
│                      └────────────┘    │     │  └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘ │
│                                        │     │                                        │
└────────────────────────────────────────┘     └────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The client wants to connect to services at the provider network, but the **Customer Firewall** has a strict policy on **HTTP filtering** and **SNI filtering**.

It will drop any unauthorized traffic, So any unallowed Domain/SNI will be dropped.

The SNI/Domain of **Envoy B** (`envoy-b.example.com`) is **allowed** in the firewall, but they **don't Allow any other domain**.

All services are HTTP/HTTPS

Here is the configuration for the envoy servers:

### Envoy - A:

- It listens on port `80`, and on every HTTP traffic, it will forward the traffic to Envoy - B using **HTTP2 + TLSv1.3**
- It listens on port `443`, and on every **TPC** traffic, it will forward the traffic to Envoy - B **without any further encryption**

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
    # HTTP
    - name: http_forwarder
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 80
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: http_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: http_forwarder
                      domains: [ "*" ]
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: forwarder_to_envoy_b_http
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

    # HTTPS/TLS
    - name: https_forwarder
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 443
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
                cluster: forwarder_to_envoy_b_tls
                stat_prefix: https_passthrough
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog

  clusters:
    - name: forwarder_to_envoy_b_http
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: forwarder_to_envoy_b_http
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: envoy-b.example.com
                      port_value: 8888

      dns_resolution_config:
        resolvers:
          - socket_address:
              address: "1.1.1.1"
              port_value: 53
        dns_resolver_options:
          no_default_search_domain: true
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_params:
              tls_minimum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
              tls_maximum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3

    - name: forwarder_to_envoy_b_tls
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: forwarder_to_envoy_b_tls
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: envoy-b.example.com
                      port_value: 8889
      dns_resolution_config:
        resolvers:
          - socket_address:
              address: "1.1.1.1"
              port_value: 53
        dns_resolver_options:
          no_default_search_domain: true
```

### Envoy - B:

- It listens on port `8888`, and on every `HTTP2 + TLSv1.3` traffic, it will **decrypt the traffic** and forward the **plain HTTP request** to services
- It listens on port `8889`, and on every **TPC** traffic, it will forward the traffic to Envoy - B **without any further encryption/decryption**

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: http_listener_0
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8888
        filter_chains:
          - filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                  stat_prefix: ingress_http
                  route_config:
                    name: local_route
                    virtual_hosts:
                      - name: local_service
                        domains: [ "*" ]
                        routes:
                          - match:
                              prefix: "/"
                            route:
                              cluster: http_cluster
                  http_filters:
                    - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
            
            transport_socket:
              name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
                common_tls_context:
                  tls_params:
                    tls_minimum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
                    tls_maximum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
                  tls_certificates:
                    certificate_chain:
                      filename: /certs/proxy-crt.pem
                    private_key:
                      filename: /certs/proxy-key.pem
                  alpn_protocols: HTTP2


    - name: tls_listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8889
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
                cluster: tls_cluster
                stat_prefix: https_passthrough
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog

  clusters:
    - name: http_cluster
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: http_cluster
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: private.service.example.com
                      port_value: 80

      dns_resolution_config:
        resolvers:
          - socket_address:
              address: "1.1.1.1"
              port_value: 53
        dns_resolver_options:
          no_default_search_domain: true


    - name: tls_cluster
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: tls_cluster
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: private.service.example.com
                      port_value: 443
      dns_resolution_config:
        resolvers:
          - socket_address:
              address: "1.1.1.1"
              port_value: 53
        dns_resolver_options:
          no_default_search_domain: true
```

### The problem

When the client sends an HTTP request, **Envoy - A** will encrypt it, and the SNI will be `envoy-b.example.com` which is allowed in the client firewall (instead of the HOST header of the original request `private.service.example.com`)

But when the client sends an HTTPS/TLS traffic, **Envoy - A** is just forwarding a **TCP stream**, so the SNI doesn't change and stays `private.service.example.com` -> As this hostname is not allowed in the firewall **it will be dropped**!

I want the traffic of the TCP proxy to get encrypted again so the SNI changes to `envoy-b.example.com` and the firewall doesn't drop the request.

I tried to add `transport_socket` for TLS traffic on both envoy hosts but it didn't work:

`Envoy A > clusters > forwarder_to_envoy_b_tls`:

```yaml
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_params:
              tls_minimum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
              tls_maximum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
```

`Envoy B > listener > tls_listener_0`:

```yaml
            transport_socket:
              name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
                common_tls_context:
                  tls_params:
                    tls_minimum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
                    tls_maximum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
                  tls_certificates:
                    certificate_chain:
                      filename: /certs/proxy-crt.pem
                    private_key:
                      filename: /certs/proxy-key.pem
                  alpn_protocols: HTTP2
```

### Notes

1. The client doesn't accept that envoy B converts HTTPS traffic to HTTP, then transfers it (using HTTPS), then again HTTPS encryption happens at Envoy A
2. We don't have access to service private keys, so if we do what is explained in note 1, the certificates changes
3. The Envoy B **REQUIRES SNI** to determine the traffic should forward to which services